# Applying Artin-Wedderburn to Finite Semisimple Rings example (720)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, artinian, semi-simple-rings

I am trying to apply Artin-Wedderburn to finite semisimple rings, but I am getting confused on determining the isomorphism classes. For an example, suppose I am trying to find all semisimple rings of order $720=2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5$. So far my argument runs like this:

We know all finite rings are Artinian so we know that the ring $ R$ is the product of matrix rings over a division ring(which is finite and therefore a field).

Now we determine the isomorphism classes. $ 1\times 1$ matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}_q $ are isomorphic to $F_q $, so for $5^1$, we will have a copy of $\mathbb{F}_5 $. For $3^2$ we have either $\mathbb{F}_9 $ or $\mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3  $. For $2^4 $ I would like to take $\mathbb{F}_{16},\mathbb{F}_8\times \mathbb{F}_2,\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_4,\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2, \mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2$ and then $ M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb{F}_2)$ and then we take products accordingly and getting twelve isomorphism classes.

$ M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb{F}_2) \times \mathbb{F}_9 \times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb{F}_2) \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{16}  \times \mathbb{F}_9\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$ \mathbb{F}_{16} \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{8}\times\mathbb{F}_{2}   \times \mathbb{F}_9\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{8}\times\mathbb{F}_{2} \times  \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{4}\times\mathbb{F}_{4}   \times \mathbb{F}_9\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{4}\times\mathbb{F}_{4} \times  \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3\times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{4}\times\mathbb{F}_{2} \times \mathbb{F}_{2}  \times  \mathbb{F}_{9} \times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{4}\times\mathbb{F}_{2} \times \mathbb{F}_{2}  \times  \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{2}\times\mathbb{F}_{2}\times\mathbb{F}_{2} \times \mathbb{F}_{2}  \times  \mathbb{F}_9 \times \mathbb{F}_5  $

$\mathbb{F}_{2}\times\mathbb{F}_{2}\times\mathbb{F}_{2} \times \mathbb{F}_{2}  \times  \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_3 \times \mathbb{F}_5  $

I have been told, however, that this is incorrect. In particular this list shouldn't include those with $\mathbb{F}_8$ and $\mathbb{F}_{16}$.

Am I missing a simple isomorphism here?

Comment: Small note: $R$ is semisimple iff $R$ is artinian and $J(R)=0$. So your second paragraph doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ElliotG I'm not sure I see your point. What redundancy are you thinking about for instance? It is never possible that $K_1\times\dots\times K_n\simeq L_1\times \dots\times L_m$ where the $K_i,L_j$ are fields, unless the $K_i$ and the $L_j$ are the same up to reordering.

Comment: For what it's worth the list looks good to me, except that it misses the $\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_4$ terms.

Comment: @Captain Lama. I was wrong; I am not being very careful today apparently.

Comment: Dang, I mean't to write, but forgot the $\mathbb{F}_4 $ terms. I will edit the question to add them. Also, thanks for the replies.

Comment: If they told you not to use $F_8$ and $F_{16}$, they were either thinking of a different problem or wrong, I think. I count 6 possibilities for the component of order divisible by $2$, and two for the component divisible by 3, and of course only one for 5, and that'll give you $12$ possible rings.   I didn't check each one you wrote but since you got 12 and they all appear to be using the right rings, I think you're done.